# Swift - Process and notification at a certain time

Tags: ios, swift

I need an indication of how to do the following process. I already looked for some ways but I didn't find any that worked as I want.

I have an application with a local database. I want once a day at a certain time for the application to read the clients and send a local notification informing who is going to have a birthday.

How do I make this process work both in the background and foreground? I also need it to run at a certain time.

I need to create a process that runs in the background and is scheduled to run at a certain time regardless of the state of the application.

Comment: You can't schedule to run at a specific time, but you don't really need to. As long as it runs at some point during the day you can schedule tomorrow's alert(s). You can use the background fetch capability to do that. When background fetch occurs, check to see if you have already run today. If not, check the database and schedule the notification

Comment: @Paulw11 I can't do it that way, because if someone registered with the birthday of the next day after I have already scheduled the notification will be missing that client. Another thing is that there is no guarantee that it will be executed.

Comment: The best thing to do is register the notifications when the user opens your app. Or, you can schedule the notification when the new record is added to the local database. You are going to have to use a few different techniques. There is no way of executing code in the background at a specific time on iOS.

Comment: It does not have to schedule a notification for each register client, since the IOS has limits of scheduled notifications. As you are saying that you cannot schedule or repeat a task in the background, I will think of some way.

Comment: If not, find a way to do as I said. I will schedule notifications for the next 7 days whenever the user opens the app.

Answer (score 0):

First, import UserNotifications

```
import UserNotifications
```

then add the following function that defines what the notification is:

```
func notification(month: Int, day: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int, text: String){

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Put your title Here (birthday)"

//or you can assign it a parameter like text so you can have a different title for each notification
    content.body = text
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: DateComponents(month: month, day: day, hour: hour, minute: minute), repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: text, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

}
```

in view did load- request using the following code:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

    }
```

then you can create notifications for very day of the year (that repeat)
I would suggest to make a for..in loop like I do below

Here's a template of the loop you can make to loop through all days

```
for x in 1...12 { 
    for y in 0...30 {
//(you can find a way to check if 30, 31, or 28 based on x, but for now I'll just do 30)



        notification(month: x, day: y, hour: 10, minute: 00, text: "here you read birthdays from your source and put them in text, you can use x and y to access current month and day")



}
}
```

by the way these notifications will run regardless state of the app

Comment: As I understand it, you only scheduled a notification for the birthday of the registered customer but I don't want that. I want to perform a task that will be executed at a certain time once a day that will read the local database and send a local notification with the list of birthdays of that day. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: The code the way you did it would not work for several things, I will quote two, the ios has a limit of 64 scheduled notifications and therefore it would not work to schedule one per day. The way you did when someone registered a new customer I would have to do the whole process of scheduling again for each day.